# What is the best way to read ∃r.∃s.C(a) for OWL 2 in plain English?

Tags: logic, owl, description-logic

We know that in OWL 2, ∃p.C denotes the class of individuals that have a value for the property p that is of type C.

When we write ∃r.∃s.C(a), what will be the best way to read this in plain English?

On a similar note, how do we read ∀r.∃s.C(a) that I can explain even to my grandmother?

Some real-life examples would be nice.

Please answer in detail analyzing each part.

Comment: verbalizing `∃r.∃s.C(a)` depends on the properties `r` and `s` - I mean, if those are noun phrases or verb phrase in English - but in general it's nothing more than a correlated sentence. And for more readability, tools sometimes also tend to make use of domain or range of those properties.

Comment: If you have `∃worksFor.∃locatedIn.EuropeanCountry(John)` - then it could be phrased in a already condensed form as *"John works for something that is located in a European country"* - which could be refined e.g. when having a range `company` for `worksFor` to *"John works for some company that is located in a European country"*  - note, technically `∃` means *at least one"* which means *"John works for at least one company"* - so in the end, it all depends on the domain and knowledge we or a tools has to verbalize those axioms

Comment: @UninformedUser Excellent comment. Could you find some free time to convert it to a full answer?